# Setting the path of Travis database for run the tests

Tags: java, maven, heroku, spring-boot, travis-ci

I have an [open source project](https://github.com/PeopleOnMap/people-on-map-site) that use Maven with Java and were defined some variables for the database connection.

> clean spring-boot:run -DJDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/peopleonmap -DJDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME=YOUR_USER -DJDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD -DSERVER_PORT=YOUR_FAVORITE_PORT

However when I run the tests with [Travis CI (click here to the log)](https://travis-ci.org/PeopleOnMap/people-on-map-site) the connection with the Travis CI database test isn't found and the tests fail. I want to know how I can fix it.

Other detail is that I use `Heroku` and for the connection database I did read in the documentation that is need set the property `spring.datasource.url` in the `application.properties` like this:

> spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}

If have an option to remove the read of `dataSource` during the tests I also considere valid, but I think that is cool and interesting run the tests with a database for the tests in Travis CI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried specifying

```
services:
  - postgresql
```

If you want another version of Postgres, you can specify it as follows:

```
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"
```

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-Builds for more details.

Comment: I forgot some important properties in the `travis.yml` file. Thank you. +1